# Service class is undefined in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. When I try to do

```
var users = await this.userService.findByAccountId(id_bd_account);
```

I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findByAccountId' of undefined

Here's my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService  } from '@nestjs/axios';
import {SaitAuthDto} from "./dto/sait-auth.dto";
import { AccountService } from "../account/account.service";
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class ServicesSaitService {
    private readonly _saitCredential: SaitAuthDto = null;
    private readonly _urlSait: string = "";
    private readonly userService: UserService;
    private saitUrl =  "sait";
    private cuitUrl = "clienteCuentaCorriente";

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpService, private readonly acountService: AccountService ) {
        this._saitCredential = new SaitAuthDto();
        this._saitCredential.usuario = process.env.SAIT_USER;
        this._saitCredential.password = process.env.SAIT_USER_PASSWORD;
        this._urlSait = process.env.SAIT_BASE_URL;
    }
    
    public async getCustomerAccountByCuil(code:string, token:string): Promise<any> {
        const url = new URL([this.saitUrl, this.cuitUrl].join('/'), this._urlSait);
        url.searchParams.append('token', token);
        url.searchParams.append('codigo',code);
        return this.http.get(url.href).toPromise().then(async (value)=>{
            var bd_account = await this.acountService.getAccountByCuit(value.data.registros[0]['cuit']);
            var id_bd_account = bd_account[0].id;
            if(bd_account.length !== 0 ){
                var users = await this.userService.findByAccountId(id_bd_account);
                console.log(users);
            }
            return value.data;
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how `ServicesSaitService` is imported and initialised.

Comment: It is imported with import { ServicesSaitService } from "../services-sait/services-sait.service"; and initialized inside the constructor as private readonly serviceSaitService: ServicesSaitService

Comment: Please edit the question to show this. The comment isn't enough to rule out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inject `userService` as dependency if it part of your module if not you should set it as module reference; here the examples:

[**Dependency injection:**](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers)

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService  } from '@nestjs/axios';
import {SaitAuthDto} from "./dto/sait-auth.dto";
import { AccountService } from "../account/account.service";
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class ServicesSaitService {
    private readonly _saitCredential: SaitAuthDto = null;
    private readonly _urlSait: string = "";
    private saitUrl =  "sait";
    private cuitUrl = "clienteCuentaCorriente";
   

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpService, private readonly acountService: AccountService,  private readonly userService: UserService) {
        this._saitCredential = new SaitAuthDto();
        this._saitCredential.usuario = process.env.SAIT_USER;
        this._saitCredential.password = process.env.SAIT_USER_PASSWORD;
        this._urlSait = process.env.SAIT_BASE_URL;
    }
    
     

    public async getCustomerAccountByCuil(code:string, token:string): Promise<any> {
        const url = new URL([this.saitUrl, this.cuitUrl].join('/'), this._urlSait);
        url.searchParams.append('token', token);
        url.searchParams.append('codigo',code);
        return this.http.get(url.href).toPromise().then(async (value)=>{
            var bd_account = await this.acountService.getAccountByCuit(value.data.registros[0]['cuit']);
            var id_bd_account = bd_account[0].id;
            if(bd_account.length !== 0 ){
                var users = await this.userService.findByAccountId(id_bd_account);
                console.log(users);
            }
            return value.data;
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        })
    }
}
```

[**Module reference**](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref)

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService  } from '@nestjs/axios';
import {SaitAuthDto} from "./dto/sait-auth.dto";
import { AccountService } from "../account/account.service";
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { ModuleRef } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class ServicesSaitService {
    private readonly _saitCredential: SaitAuthDto = null;
    private readonly _urlSait: string = "";
    private saitUrl =  "sait";
    private cuitUrl = "clienteCuentaCorriente";
    private readonly userService: UserService
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpService, private readonly acountService: AccountService, private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {
        this._saitCredential = new SaitAuthDto();
        this._saitCredential.usuario = process.env.SAIT_USER;
        this._saitCredential.password = process.env.SAIT_USER_PASSWORD;
        this._urlSait = process.env.SAIT_BASE_URL;
    }
    onModuleInit() {
      this.userService = this.moduleRef.get(UserService, {
       strict: false,
      });
     }
    
    public async getCustomerAccountByCuil(code:string, token:string): Promise<any> {
        const url = new URL([this.saitUrl, this.cuitUrl].join('/'), this._urlSait);
        url.searchParams.append('token', token);
        url.searchParams.append('codigo',code);
        return this.http.get(url.href).toPromise().then(async (value)=>{
            var bd_account = await this.acountService.getAccountByCuit(value.data.registros[0]['cuit']);
            var id_bd_account = bd_account[0].id;
            if(bd_account.length !== 0 ){
                var users = await this.userService.findByAccountId(id_bd_account);
                console.log(users);
            }
            return value.data;
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked. Just had to add import { ModuleRef } from '@nestjs/core'; to the second option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move
`private readonly userService: UserService;` to the constructor so it will be dependency injected. Your code should read:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService  } from '@nestjs/axios';
import {SaitAuthDto} from "./dto/sait-auth.dto";
import { AccountService } from "../account/account.service";
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class ServicesSaitService {
    private readonly _saitCredential: SaitAuthDto = null;
    private readonly _urlSait: string = "";
    private saitUrl =  "sait";
    private cuitUrl = "clienteCuentaCorriente";

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpService, private readonly acountService: AccountService, private readonly userService: UserService ) {
        this._saitCredential = new SaitAuthDto();
        this._saitCredential.usuario = process.env.SAIT_USER;
        this._saitCredential.password = process.env.SAIT_USER_PASSWORD;
        this._urlSait = process.env.SAIT_BASE_URL;
    }
    
    public async getCustomerAccountByCuil(code:string, token:string): Promise<any> {
        const url = new URL([this.saitUrl, this.cuitUrl].join('/'), this._urlSait);
        url.searchParams.append('token', token);
        url.searchParams.append('codigo',code);
        return this.http.get(url.href).toPromise().then(async (value)=>{
            var bd_account = await this.acountService.getAccountByCuit(value.data.registros[0]['cuit']);
            var id_bd_account = bd_account[0].id;
            if(bd_account.length !== 0 ){
                var users = await this.userService.findByAccountId(id_bd_account);
                console.log(users);
            }
            return value.data;
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.userService isn't defined. You need to add it as a dependency to your constructor:

```
      constructor(private readonly http: HttpService, private readonly acountService: AccountService, private userService: UserService) {
           this._saitCredential = new SaitAuthDto();
           this._saitCredential.usuario = process.env.SAIT_USER;
           this._saitCredential.password = process.env.SAIT_USER_PASSWORD;
           this._urlSait = process.env.SAIT_BASE_URL;
      }
```